# Read/Write to/from PageFile

Tags: c#, java, delphi, read-write, pagefile

I use an embedded DB for two applications that one of them is Server and another one is client.The client side app. can send fetch data request to server side to retrieve data and show in a table (or sth else).Question is this:
How may I save(write) fetched data into pagefile and read that from it when needed(in java, Delphi or c#)?

Comment: Not sure why you got downvoted at the first place. No such thing as stupid questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Shared Memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) mechanism. It effectively allocates a chunk of memory in the page file and allows inter-process sharing.

Note: since you specified Delphi and C# tags, I assume you have access to WinAPI functions, such as `CreateFileMapping` and `MapViewOfFile`.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is fetched out from the server-side to client-side as in a JTable successfully.For saving the fetched data you have to read the cell data of table and save that data into a text file format in a particular directory. When you re-run your application you can easily pick your saved data from that directory.

Comment: Isn't any way to access pagefile?Writing data into a file is very simple but I don't want to use this type of files.I wanna use a kind of file that users can not access it's data easily.

Comment: first clear the things you want ? Your application is Client-Server application.If user save the fetched data,then make this data non-editable for next time.